# Unmarshaling XML in go with xsdgen

Tags: go, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an xml file with golang.
I've used xsdgen to generate the struct part

I cannot parse the file with `xml.Unmarshal(byteValue, &data)`
I expected the program to print : GrandTotalAmount.Value which is 671.15 but it is printing 0.

The variable `data` seems empty, as this line didn't worked as i expected :
`xml.Unmarshal(byteValue, &data)`

I haven't seen any errors compiling (or i don't know where to find them)

I feel like i am missing something, can you help me please ?

XSD files : https://gist.github.com/hyperi0n/a5eb805d9f91de84d341ea75cfe6d1bf

XML file :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<rsm:CrossIndustryInvoice xmlns:qdt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:QualifiedDataType:100" xmlns:ram="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100" xmlns:rsm="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:CrossIndustryInvoice:100" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <rsm:ExchangedDocumentContext>
    <ram:GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter>
      <ram:ID>urn:factur-x.eu:1p0:minimum</ram:ID>
    </ram:GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter>
  </rsm:ExchangedDocumentContext>
  <rsm:ExchangedDocument>
    <ram:ID>FA-2017-0010</ram:ID>
    <ram:TypeCode>380</ram:TypeCode>
    <ram:IssueDateTime>
      <udt:DateTimeString format="102">20171113</udt:DateTimeString>
    </ram:IssueDateTime>
  </rsm:ExchangedDocument>
  <rsm:SupplyChainTradeTransaction>
    <ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeAgreement>
      <ram:SellerTradeParty>
        <ram:Name>Au bon moulin</ram:Name>
        <ram:SpecifiedLegalOrganization>
          <ram:ID schemeID="0002">99999999800010</ram:ID>
        </ram:SpecifiedLegalOrganization>
        <ram:PostalTradeAddress>
          <ram:CountryID>FR</ram:CountryID>
        </ram:PostalTradeAddress>
        <ram:SpecifiedTaxRegistration>
          <ram:ID schemeID="VA">FR11999999998</ram:ID>
        </ram:SpecifiedTaxRegistration>
      </ram:SellerTradeParty>
      <ram:BuyerTradeParty>
        <ram:Name>Ma jolie boutique</ram:Name>
        <ram:SpecifiedLegalOrganization>
          <ram:ID schemeID="0002">78787878400035</ram:ID>
        </ram:SpecifiedLegalOrganization>
        <ram:PostalTradeAddress>
          <ram:CountryID>FR</ram:CountryID>
        </ram:PostalTradeAddress>
        <ram:SpecifiedTaxRegistration>
          <ram:ID schemeID="VA">FR19787878784</ram:ID>
        </ram:SpecifiedTaxRegistration>
      </ram:BuyerTradeParty>
      <ram:BuyerOrderReferencedDocument>
        <ram:IssuerAssignedID>PO445</ram:IssuerAssignedID>
      </ram:BuyerOrderReferencedDocument>
    </ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeAgreement>
    <ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeDelivery/>
    <ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeSettlement>
      <ram:InvoiceCurrencyCode>EUR</ram:InvoiceCurrencyCode>
      <ram:SpecifiedTradeSettlementHeaderMonetarySummation>
        <ram:TaxBasisTotalAmount>624.90</ram:TaxBasisTotalAmount>
        <ram:TaxTotalAmount currencyID="EUR">46.25</ram:TaxTotalAmount>
        <ram:GrandTotalAmount>671.15</ram:GrandTotalAmount>
        <ram:DuePayableAmount>470.15</ram:DuePayableAmount>
      </ram:SpecifiedTradeSettlementHeaderMonetarySummation>
    </ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeSettlement>
  </rsm:SupplyChainTradeTransaction>
</rsm:CrossIndustryInvoice>
```

Go file :

```
    package main
    
    import (
        "encoding/xml"
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "os"
    )
    
    type AmountType struct {
        Value      float64 `xml:",chardata"`
        CurrencyID string  `xml:"currencyID,attr,omitempty"`
    }
    
    // May be one of 1A, AD, AE, AF, AG, AI, AL, AM, AO, AQ, AR, AS, AT, AU, AW, AX, AZ, BA, BB, BD, BE, BF, BG, BH, BI, BJ, BL, BM, BN, BO, BQ, BR, BS, BT, BV, BW, BY, BZ, CA, CC, CD, CF, CG, CH, CI, CK, CL, CM, CN, CO, CR, CU, CV, CW, CX, CY, CZ, DE, DJ, DK, DM, DO, DZ, EC, EE, EG, EH, ER, ES, ET, FI, FJ, FK, FM, FO, FR, GA, GB, GD, GE, GF, GG, GH, GI, GL, GM, GN, GP, GQ, GR, GS, GT, GU, GW, GY, HK, HM, HN, HR, HT, HU, ID, IE, IL, IM, IN, IO, IQ, IR, IS, IT, JE, JM, JO, JP, KE, KG, KH, KI, KM, KN, KP, KR, KW, KY, KZ, LA, LB, LC, LI, LK, LR, LS, LT, LU, LV, LY, MA, MC, MD, ME, MF, MG, MH, MK, ML, MM, MN, MO, MP, MQ, MR, MS, MT, MU, MV, MW, MX, MY, MZ, NA, NC, NE, NF, NG, NI, NL, NO, NP, NR, NU, NZ, OM, PA, PE, PF, PG, PH, PK, PL, PM, PN, PR, PS, PT, PW, PY, QA, RE, RO, RS, RU, RW, SA, SB, SC, SD, SE, SG, SH, SI, SJ, SK, SL, SM, SN, SO, SR, SS, ST, SV, SX, SY, SZ, TC, TD, TF, TG, TH, TJ, TK, TL, TM, TN, TO, TR, TT, TV, TW, TZ, UA, UG, UM, US, UY, UZ, VA, VC, VE, VG, VI, VN, VU, WF, WS, YE, YT, ZA, ZM, ZW
    type CountryIDContentType string
    
    type CrossIndustryInvoiceType struct {
        ExchangedDocumentContext    ExchangedDocumentContextType    `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100 ExchangedDocumentContext"`
        ExchangedDocument           ExchangedDocumentType           `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100 ExchangedDocument"`
        SupplyChainTradeTransaction SupplyChainTradeTransactionType `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100 SupplyChainTradeTransaction"`
    }
    
    // May be one of AED, AFN, ALL, AMD, ANG, AOA, ARS, AUD, AWG, AZN, BAM, BBD, BDT, BGN, BHD, BIF, BMD, BND, BOB, BOV, BRL, BSD, BTN, BWP, BYN, BZD, CAD, CDF, CHE, CHF, CHW, CLF, CLP, CNY, COP, COU, CRC, CUC, CUP, CVE, CZK, DJF, DKK, DOP, DZD, EGP, ERN, ETB, EUR, FJD, FKP, GBP, GEL, GHS, GIP, GMD, GNF, GTQ, GYD, HKD, HNL, HRK, HTG, HUF, IDR, ILS, INR, IQD, IRR, ISK, JMD, JOD, JPY, KES, KGS, KHR, KMF, KPW, KRW, KWD, KYD, KZT, LAK, LBP, LKR, LRD, LSL, LYD, MAD, MDL, MGA, MKD, MMK, MNT, MOP, MRU, MUR, MVR, MWK, MXN, MXV, MYR, MZN, NAD, NGN, NIO, NOK, NPR, NZD, OMR, PAB, PEN, PGK, PHP, PKR, PLN, PYG, QAR, RON, RSD, RUB, RWF, SAR, SBD, SCR, SDG, SEK, SGD, SHP, SLL, SOS, SRD, SSP, STN, SVC, SYP, SZL, THB, TJS, TMT, TND, TOP, TRY, TTD, TWD, TZS, UAH, UGX, USD, USN, UYI, UYU, UYW, UZS, VES, VND, VUV, WST, XAF, XAG, XAU, XBA, XBB, XBC, XBD, XCD, XDR, XOF, XPD, XPF, XPT, XSU, XTS, XUA, XXX, YER, ZAR, ZMW, ZWL
    type CurrencyCodeContentType string
    
    type DateTimeString struct {
        Value  string `xml:",chardata"`
        Format string `xml:"format,attr"`
    }
    
    type DateTimeType struct {
        DateTimeString DateTimeString `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100 DateTimeString"`
    }
    
    // May be one of 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 130, 202, 203, 204, 211, 261, 262, 295, 296, 308, 325, 326, 380, 381, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 393, 394, 395, 396, 420, 456, 457, 458, 527, 575, 623, 633, 751, 780, 935
    type DocumentCodeContentType string
    
    type DocumentContextParameterType struct {
        ID IDType `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100 ID,omitempty"`
    }
    
    type ExchangedDocumentContextType struct {
        BusinessProcessSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter DocumentContextParameterType `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100 BusinessProcessSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter,omitempty"`
        GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter       DocumentContextParameterType `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100 GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter"`
    }
    
    type ExchangedDocumentType struct {
        ID            IDType                  `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100 ID"`
        TypeCode      DocumentCodeContentType `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:QualifiedDataType:100 TypeCode"`
        IssueDateTime DateTimeType            `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100 IssueDateTime"`
    }
    
    type HeaderTradeAgreementType struct {
        BuyerReference               string                 `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100 BuyerReference,omitempty"`
        SellerTradeParty             TradePartyType         `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100 SellerTradeParty"`
        BuyerTradeParty              TradePartyType         `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100 BuyerTradeParty"`
        BuyerOrderReferencedDocument ReferencedDocumentType `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100 BuyerOrderReferencedDocument,omitempty"`
    }
    
    type HeaderTradeDeliveryType struct {
    }
    
    type HeaderTradeSettlementType struct {
        InvoiceCurrencyCode                             CurrencyCodeContentType                    `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:QualifiedDataType:100 InvoiceCurrencyCode"`
        SpecifiedTradeSettlementHeaderMonetarySummation TradeSettlementHeaderMonetarySummationType `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100 SpecifiedTradeSettlementHeaderMonetarySummation"`
    }
    
    type IDType struct {
        Value    string `xml:",chardata"`
        SchemeID string `xml:"schemeID,attr,omitempty"`
    }
    
    type LegalOrganizationType struct {
        ID IDType `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100 ID,omitempty"`
    }
    
    type ReferencedDocumentType struct {
        IssuerAssignedID IDType `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100 IssuerAssignedID"`
    }
    
    type SupplyChainTradeTransactionType struct {
        ApplicableHeaderTradeAgreement  HeaderTradeAgreementType  `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100 ApplicableHeaderTradeAgreement"`
        ApplicableHeaderTradeDelivery   HeaderTradeDeliveryType   `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100 ApplicableHeaderTradeDelivery"`
        ApplicableHeaderTradeSettlement HeaderTradeSettlementType `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100 ApplicableHeaderTradeSettlement"`
    }
    
    type TaxRegistrationType struct {
        ID IDType `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100 ID"`
    }
    
    type TradeAddressType struct {
        PostcodeCode           string               `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100 PostcodeCode,omitempty"`
        LineOne                string               `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100 LineOne,omitempty"`
        LineTwo                string               `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100 LineTwo,omitempty"`
        LineThree              string               `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100 LineThree,omitempty"`
        CityName               string               `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100 CityName,omitempty"`
        CountryID              CountryIDContentType `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:QualifiedDataType:100 CountryID"`
        CountrySubDivisionName string               `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100 CountrySubDivisionName,omitempty"`
    }
    
    type TradePartyType struct {
        Name                       string                `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100 Name"`
        SpecifiedLegalOrganization LegalOrganizationType `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100 SpecifiedLegalOrganization,omitempty"`
        PostalTradeAddress         TradeAddressType      `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100 PostalTradeAddress,omitempty"`
        SpecifiedTaxRegistration   []TaxRegistrationType `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100 SpecifiedTaxRegistration,omitempty"`
    }
    
    type TradeSettlementHeaderMonetarySummationType struct {
        TaxBasisTotalAmount AmountType `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100 TaxBasisTotalAmount"`
        TaxTotalAmount      AmountType `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100 TaxTotalAmount,omitempty"`
        GrandTotalAmount    AmountType `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100 GrandTotalAmount"`
        DuePayableAmount    AmountType `xml:"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100 DuePayableAmount"`
    }
    
    func main() {
    
        xmlFile, err := os.Open("invoice.xml")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        defer xmlFile.Close()
    
        byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)
    
        fmt.Println(string(byteValue))
    
        var data CrossIndustryInvoiceType

        xml.Unmarshal(byteValue, &data)
        
fmt.Println(data.SupplyChainTradeTransaction.ApplicableHeaderTradeSettlement.SpecifiedTradeSettlementHeaderMonetarySummation.GrandTotalAmount.Value)
    }
```

Comment: What does "cannot parse the file" mean? What error, or other unexpected behavior do you see?

Comment: I expected the program to print : GrandTotalAmount.Value which is 671.15 but it is printing 0.  The variable data seems empty, as if the xml.Unmarshal(byteValue, &data) didn't worked as i expected

Comment: And if you stop ignoring errors, what do they tell you?

Comment: Where is the `xsd` (XML Schema Definitionion) file? `xsdgen` requires `xsd`; could you please post that as well?

Comment: I've tried to edit my question including the xsd files, first time asking here sorry if it is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to [Go Issue #13400](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13400). There seems to be an issue with the namespace prefixes. You can in fact ignore the prefixes in your struct tags while Unmarshaling.

The following code should work for you:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
)

type AmountType struct {
    Value      float64 `xml:",chardata"`
    CurrencyID string  `xml:"currencyID,attr,omitempty"`
}

// May be one of 1A, AD, AE, AF, AG, AI, AL, AM, AO, AQ, AR, AS, AT, AU, AW, AX, AZ, BA, BB, BD, BE, BF, BG, BH, BI, BJ, BL, BM, BN, BO, BQ, BR, BS, BT, BV, BW, BY, BZ, CA, CC, CD, CF, CG, CH, CI, CK, CL, CM, CN, CO, CR, CU, CV, CW, CX, CY, CZ, DE, DJ, DK, DM, DO, DZ, EC, EE, EG, EH, ER, ES, ET, FI, FJ, FK, FM, FO, FR, GA, GB, GD, GE, GF, GG, GH, GI, GL, GM, GN, GP, GQ, GR, GS, GT, GU, GW, GY, HK, HM, HN, HR, HT, HU, ID, IE, IL, IM, IN, IO, IQ, IR, IS, IT, JE, JM, JO, JP, KE, KG, KH, KI, KM, KN, KP, KR, KW, KY, KZ, LA, LB, LC, LI, LK, LR, LS, LT, LU, LV, LY, MA, MC, MD, ME, MF, MG, MH, MK, ML, MM, MN, MO, MP, MQ, MR, MS, MT, MU, MV, MW, MX, MY, MZ, NA, NC, NE, NF, NG, NI, NL, NO, NP, NR, NU, NZ, OM, PA, PE, PF, PG, PH, PK, PL, PM, PN, PR, PS, PT, PW, PY, QA, RE, RO, RS, RU, RW, SA, SB, SC, SD, SE, SG, SH, SI, SJ, SK, SL, SM, SN, SO, SR, SS, ST, SV, SX, SY, SZ, TC, TD, TF, TG, TH, TJ, TK, TL, TM, TN, TO, TR, TT, TV, TW, TZ, UA, UG, UM, US, UY, UZ, VA, VC, VE, VG, VI, VN, VU, WF, WS, YE, YT, ZA, ZM, ZW
type CountryIDContentType string

type CrossIndustryInvoiceType struct {
    ExchangedDocumentContext    ExchangedDocumentContextType    `xml:"ExchangedDocumentContext"`
    ExchangedDocument           ExchangedDocumentType           `xml:"ExchangedDocument"`
    SupplyChainTradeTransaction SupplyChainTradeTransactionType `xml:"SupplyChainTradeTransaction"`
}

// May be one of AED, AFN, ALL, AMD, ANG, AOA, ARS, AUD, AWG, AZN, BAM, BBD, BDT, BGN, BHD, BIF, BMD, BND, BOB, BOV, BRL, BSD, BTN, BWP, BYN, BZD, CAD, CDF, CHE, CHF, CHW, CLF, CLP, CNY, COP, COU, CRC, CUC, CUP, CVE, CZK, DJF, DKK, DOP, DZD, EGP, ERN, ETB, EUR, FJD, FKP, GBP, GEL, GHS, GIP, GMD, GNF, GTQ, GYD, HKD, HNL, HRK, HTG, HUF, IDR, ILS, INR, IQD, IRR, ISK, JMD, JOD, JPY, KES, KGS, KHR, KMF, KPW, KRW, KWD, KYD, KZT, LAK, LBP, LKR, LRD, LSL, LYD, MAD, MDL, MGA, MKD, MMK, MNT, MOP, MRU, MUR, MVR, MWK, MXN, MXV, MYR, MZN, NAD, NGN, NIO, NOK, NPR, NZD, OMR, PAB, PEN, PGK, PHP, PKR, PLN, PYG, QAR, RON, RSD, RUB, RWF, SAR, SBD, SCR, SDG, SEK, SGD, SHP, SLL, SOS, SRD, SSP, STN, SVC, SYP, SZL, THB, TJS, TMT, TND, TOP, TRY, TTD, TWD, TZS, UAH, UGX, USD, USN, UYI, UYU, UYW, UZS, VES, VND, VUV, WST, XAF, XAG, XAU, XBA, XBB, XBC, XBD, XCD, XDR, XOF, XPD, XPF, XPT, XSU, XTS, XUA, XXX, YER, ZAR, ZMW, ZWL
type CurrencyCodeContentType string

type DateTimeString struct {
    Value  string `xml:",chardata"`
    Format string `xml:"format,attr"`
}

type DateTimeType struct {
    DateTimeString DateTimeString `xml:"DateTimeString"`
}

// May be one of 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 130, 202, 203, 204, 211, 261, 262, 295, 296, 308, 325, 326, 380, 381, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 393, 394, 395, 396, 420, 456, 457, 458, 527, 575, 623, 633, 751, 780, 935
type DocumentCodeContentType string

type DocumentContextParameterType struct {
    ID IDType `xml:"ID,omitempty"`
}

type ExchangedDocumentContextType struct {
    BusinessProcessSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter DocumentContextParameterType `xml:"BusinessProcessSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter,omitempty"`
    GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter       DocumentContextParameterType `xml:"GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter"`
}

type ExchangedDocumentType struct {
    ID            IDType                  `xml:"ID"`
    TypeCode      DocumentCodeContentType `xml:"TypeCode"`
    IssueDateTime DateTimeType            `xml:"IssueDateTime"`
}

type HeaderTradeAgreementType struct {
    BuyerReference               string                 `xml:"BuyerReference,omitempty"`
    SellerTradeParty             TradePartyType         `xml:"SellerTradeParty"`
    BuyerTradeParty              TradePartyType         `xml:"BuyerTradeParty"`
    BuyerOrderReferencedDocument ReferencedDocumentType `xml:"BuyerOrderReferencedDocument,omitempty"`
}

type HeaderTradeDeliveryType struct {
}

type HeaderTradeSettlementType struct {
    InvoiceCurrencyCode                             CurrencyCodeContentType                    `xml:"InvoiceCurrencyCode"`
    SpecifiedTradeSettlementHeaderMonetarySummation TradeSettlementHeaderMonetarySummationType `xml:"SpecifiedTradeSettlementHeaderMonetarySummation"`
}

type IDType struct {
    Value    string `xml:",chardata"`
    SchemeID string `xml:"schemeID,attr,omitempty"`
}

type LegalOrganizationType struct {
    ID IDType `xml:"ID,omitempty"`
}

type ReferencedDocumentType struct {
    IssuerAssignedID IDType `xml:"IssuerAssignedID"`
}

type SupplyChainTradeTransactionType struct {
    ApplicableHeaderTradeAgreement  HeaderTradeAgreementType  `xml:"ApplicableHeaderTradeAgreement"`
    ApplicableHeaderTradeDelivery   HeaderTradeDeliveryType   `xml:"ApplicableHeaderTradeDelivery"`
    ApplicableHeaderTradeSettlement HeaderTradeSettlementType `xml:"ApplicableHeaderTradeSettlement"`
}

type TaxRegistrationType struct {
    ID IDType `xml:"ID"`
}

type TradeAddressType struct {
    PostcodeCode           string               `xml:"PostcodeCode,omitempty"`
    LineOne                string               `xml:"LineOne,omitempty"`
    LineTwo                string               `xml:"LineTwo,omitempty"`
    LineThree              string               `xml:"LineThree,omitempty"`
    CityName               string               `xml:"CityName,omitempty"`
    CountryID              CountryIDContentType `xml:"CountryID"`
    CountrySubDivisionName string               `xml:"CountrySubDivisionName,omitempty"`
}

type TradePartyType struct {
    Name                       string                `xml:"Name"`
    SpecifiedLegalOrganization LegalOrganizationType `xml:"SpecifiedLegalOrganization,omitempty"`
    PostalTradeAddress         TradeAddressType      `xml:"PostalTradeAddress,omitempty"`
    SpecifiedTaxRegistration   []TaxRegistrationType `xml:"SpecifiedTaxRegistration,omitempty"`
}

type TradeSettlementHeaderMonetarySummationType struct {
    TaxBasisTotalAmount AmountType `xml:"TaxBasisTotalAmount"`
    TaxTotalAmount      AmountType `xml:"TaxTotalAmount,omitempty"`
    GrandTotalAmount    AmountType `xml:"GrandTotalAmount"`
    DuePayableAmount    AmountType `xml:"DuePayableAmount"`
}

func main() {
    xmlFile, err := os.Open("invoice.xml")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    byted, err := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    xmlFile.Close()

    var data CrossIndustryInvoiceType
    if err := xml.Unmarshal(byted, &data); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", data.SupplyChainTradeTransaction.ApplicableHeaderTradeSettlement.SpecifiedTradeSettlementHeaderMonetarySummation.GrandTotalAmount.Value)
}
```

Output:

```
671.15
```

Answer (score -1):

When I used xsdgen to generate related go code for ISO20022, I had the same problem. It should be the some matters inside the xsdgen package. I have read all the options about the xsdgen's config, but there are no option for ignoring the addition of namespace with XMLTag.

You might concentrate on the implemention of the xsdgen package, or just manually omit the extra namespaces on the base of generated code.